# How to show previous firebase push notifications on notification screen in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications

I need to show list of notifications history to users on my flutter application. Is there a way that I can get all the notifications history from firebase against each user or do I need to store it in my db may be firestore against each user id, like when a notification is generated it is sent to around 100 users for example, do I need to update all 100 users profile data to add that notification id and when showing on flutter app it will get the notification id and show the content to all users (in case if specific notifications are to be sent to particular users) ? will that not effect the application performance?

Is there any better approach?

Comment: i dont know if there is any way you can get history. but you can save notification data in db.